# Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I am receiving an error when attempting to pull several rows of data from my MySQL database and display their content on my web page. Since I am very new to Code Igniter, i am not sure how to fix this error:

Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Here is the code associated with the error.

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class news_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function get_news()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $row) 
        {
            $array[] = get_object_vars($row);
        }
        return $array;
    }
}

}?>
```

Controller:

```
    <?php
class profile extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html'));
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $details = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('uid'));
        $data['uname'] = $details[0]->fname . " " . $details[0]->lname;
        $data['uemail'] = $details[0]->email;
        $data['ustorenumber'] = $details[0]-> storenumber;
        $data['urank'] = $details[0]-> rank;
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);//Error reported on this line.
    }
}
```

View:

```
                <?php
                foreach($news AS $row) {
                    echo '<p>' . $row->content . '</p>';//Error reported on this line
                }
            ?>
```

Full Error:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/profile_view.php

Line Number: 82

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cig\application\views\profile_view.php
Line: 82
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cig\application\controllers\profile.php
Line: 22
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cig\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0):

In model return result in object format.Like this..

```
function get_news()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result();//returns result in object format
    }
}
```

**OR**

**IN view:** use `$row['content']` insetad of `$row->content;`

```
 <?php
            foreach($news AS $row) {
                echo '<p>' . $row['content']. '</p>';//Error reported on this line
            }
        ?>
```